# sql server select query

Tags: sql-server

When I run a `SELECT` query in SQL Server Management Studio that has a `WHERE` clause and the database is located on the network, is the query 'run' on the Server or my Desktop PC, eg. will the entire table be brought back from the server and then filtered on my PC or will the filtering be done on the Server?

Does this behaviour differ if I'm using MS Access to run the query against the (remote) database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Database has it's database engine which does all request handling. So, when you connect to a database server, it opens a channel and accept the request with parameters and then does all housekeeping and returns you the desired result back. It only returns the result of the query and it happens on the server.